# Passing \ inside stored procedure Input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Thanks for looking into my post.

I have created a procedure and trying to pass a value which contains \ inside parameter but its throwing error.

Please let me know how to pass \ inside the parameter.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DeltaCheck
    @ServerName nvarchar(30)
AS
    INSERT INTO Space
        EXECUTE [@ServerName].master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb ' '
GO

EXEC DeltaCheck @ServerName = 'Hello\TestA'
```

Comment: I don't think `\\` is the point: you can't specify the server name with a parameter

Comment: Is there any way that we can achieve it?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only way. Don't forget to use `QUOTENAME()` to get the bracketing correct

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL. Execute accepts a `@module_name_var` so you can concatenate the four part name into a variable and execute that - `EXEC @var` is safer than `EXEC (@var)` because SQL Server validates that `@var` is an object name and calls it rather than just executing any arbitrary SQL

Comment: FYI that statement above won't work on the unsupported SQL Server 2008, or soon to be unsupported 2012; `CREATE OR ALTER` was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` isn't an issue.

The grammar doesn't support arbitrary replacements as you are attempting.

It *does* [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments:%7E:text=%40module_name_var,-Is) parameterising the entire object name though so you can do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeltaCheck @ServerName SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ObjectName NVARCHAR(1000) = QUOTENAME(@ServerName)  + '.master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb'

    INSERT INTO Space
    EXECUTE @ObjectName '...'
END
```